# Find size of an image in javascript without using file property as it is not supported in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, filesize

![enter image description here][1]I want to validate image size before submitting form via javascript. But in eclipse:

```
var filesize=filename.files[0].size
```

where filename is var that stores path of image is not working.

It is not supported. Can any one please help me to find solution of this or tell me any other alternative to check size of image on client side before submitting the form

Comment: `filename` will have to be an HTMLInputElement for your code to make sense

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="validateFileSize()">
<input type="file" id="myFile"  onchange="validateFileSize()">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var maxSizeBytes=10000;
function validateFileSize(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in myFile) {
        var file = x.files[0];
        if ('size' in file) {
                    if(file.size >maxSizeBytes)
                     alert("Invalid file size.Maximum allowed size is "+maxSizeBytes+" bytes");
            txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
         }
    }    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir I am making this project in eclipse indigo

Comment: Are you checking your application in eclipse  internal browser?is this a web application or mobile hybrid app?

Comment: Yes sir I am using internal browser of eclipse. And this is a web application

Comment: Eclipse internal browser dosen't support file input type but this code works fine in all major desktop browsers (IE10+,Chrome all versions,FF31+,Safari 5.1 + , Opera 26+).And it would be better if you can use a real desktop browser for testing because at the end of the day your application will be running on one of them.
Check this http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple